# ethers.js - How to confirm if transaction has been mined successfully or not?

Tags: transactions, ethers.js, uniswap, pending-transactions

I have a script which calls a smart contract method `swapExactinputSingle(amtIn)`. I want to make sure that once this particular method call is successful, then only the code lines to print updated balances should run. I tried using the following approach:

```
   const singleSwap = new ethers.Contract(
      singleSwapAddress,
      swapjson.abi,
      provider
   );

// ... ... ...

   const transaction = await singleSwap
      .connect(accounts[0])
      .swapExactInputSingle(amtIn, {
         gasLimit: 270000,
      }); // swapExactInputSingle() is the contract function.

   console.log(transaction.hash);  // works fine

   const receipt = await provider.getTransactionReceipt(transaction.hash);  // receipt comes null.

   if (receipt) {
      console.log(   // print updated balances.
         "WMATIC balance after single swap: ",
         await wmatic.balanceOf(accounts[0].address)
      );
   }
```

In above code, the receipt value comes as null. Also if I directly print the updated balances right after calling the contract method `swapExactinputSingle()`, then it prints old balances instead of updated ones. However, I want to print updated balances only after the method call transaction gets mined and updated on blockchain. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anyways, I got the solution myself. We can use `transaction.wait().then()` to do so. Here is the code:

```js
       const transaction = await singleSwap
          .connect(accounts[0])
          .swapExactInputSingle(amtIn, {
             gasLimit: 270000,
          }); // call contract function.
    
       transaction.wait().then(async (receipt) => {
          // console.log(receipt);
          if (receipt && receipt.status == 1) {
             // transaction success.
             console.log(
                "WMATIC balance after single swap: ",
                await wmatic.balanceOf(accounts[0].address)  // print updated balances.
             );
          }
       });
```